Why are my GAN implementation not converging?
   class GAN:        
       def generator_loss(_, y_pred):
        # y_pred = D(G(noise))
        return tfm.reduce_sum(tfm.log(y_pred)) / y_pred.shape[0]

    def fit(self, X, batch_size, discriminator_arch, generator_arch, iter, noise_dim=1000, k=10):
        img_shape = X.shape[1:]
        self.noise_dim = noise_dim

        D_input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=X.shape[1:])
        G_input_tensor = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(noise_dim,))

        layers, D_tensor = discriminator_arch(D_input_tensor)

        discriminator = tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=[D_input_tensor], 
            outputs = D_tensor)
        
        G_tensor = generator_arch(G_input_tensor, img_shape)

        generator = tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=[G_input_tensor], 
            outputs=G_tensor)
        
        D_G_tensor = G_tensor
        for layer in layers:
            D_G_tensor = layer(D_G_tensor)
        
        gradient_computer = tf.keras.Model(
            inputs=[G_input_tensor], 
            outputs=D_G_tensor)
        
        gradient_computer.compile(
            optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
            loss='binary_crossentropy')
        
        D_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
        
        discriminator.compile(
            optimizer=D_optimizer,
            loss='binary_crossentropy')
        
        dummy_Y = np.zeros((batch_size * 2, 1))
        dummy_Y[:batch_size] = 1.0 # real!

        # log(...) -> 1
        # log(1 - ...) -> 0
        
        for _ in range(iter):
            GAN.change_discriminator_trainable(discriminator, D_optimizer, True)
            for __ in range(k):
                # generate noise
                indices = np.random.choice(len(X), size=batch_size, replace=False)
                X_random = X[indices]
                Z = np.random.normal(size=(batch_size, noise_dim))

                discriminator.fit(
                    [np.vstack((X_random, generator.predict(Z)))],
                    dummy_Y, batch_size=batch_size * 2) # Y is not used

            GAN.change_discriminator_trainable(discriminator, D_optimizer, False)

            Z = np.random.normal(size=(batch_size, noise_dim,))

            # print(f'before average D(x) = {np.mean(discriminator.predict(X))}')
            gradient_computer.fit(Z, dummy_Y[:batch_size],
                                      batch_size=batch_size) # Z is not used
            # gradient_computer.summary()
            print(f'average D(x) = {np.mean(discriminator.predict(X))}')

        self.generator = generator

    def change_discriminator_trainable(model, opt, unlocked):
        for layer in model.layers:
            layer.trainable = unlocked

        model.compile(optimizer=opt,
            loss='binary_crossentropy')

    def generate(self, num_pics):
        Z = np.random.normal(size=(num_pics, self.noise_dim))

        return self.generator.predict(Z)
    
def simple_D_arch(input_tensor):
    output_tensor = input_tensor

    # Maxout - Maxout - sigmoid
    # layers = [
    #     tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    #     MaxoutLayer(64, math.prod(output_tensor.shape[1:]), 5),
    #     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    #     MaxoutLayer(32, 64, 5),
    #     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    #     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
    # ]

    layers = [
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            1024,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            512,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            256,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
    ]

    for layer in layers:
        output_tensor = layer(output_tensor)
    
    return layers, output_tensor

def simple_G_arch(input_tensor, img_shape):
    layers = [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            256,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            512,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            1024,
            activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            math.prod(img_shape), # ignore dynamic entry 
            activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid),
        tf.keras.layers.Reshape(img_shape)
    ]

    output_tensor = input_tensor
    for layer in layers:
        output_tensor = layer(output_tensor)

    return output_tensor

I'm training my own GAN on this dataset on Kaggle: Butterfly. When k=1, the model seems fine in terms of loss values of D and G, but the "average D(x)" of D net seems unstable. It bounces from 0.4 to 1.0, which proves the model not converging. What's wrong with my implementation ? :(
I tried to tune every possible things but the problem with training persist.
